# openvpn is blocking external request to webserver and ssh

Tags: linux, openvpn, iptables, raspberry-pi, raspbian

My setup:
Raspberry pi 3
OS: raspbian 9 (stretch)
local network (eth0): 192.168.0.X
wireless network(wlan0): 192.168.10.X

This setup is behind a modem/router which provides access to the internet.

Ok what I'm trying to do here is to make the pi function as a vpn router and a webserver. it should work in such a way that all the traffic that comes from the wlan0(192.168.10.X) should be send through VPN connection. Every other traffic should pass through eth0(192.168.0.X) as it was working in the past.

I used the following tutorials:

https://raspberrypihq.com/how-to-turn-a-raspberry-pi-into-a-wifi-router/

https://thepi.io/how-to-use-your-raspberry-pi-as-a-vpn-router/

Now I got the part where vpn is working correctly and the wlan0(192.168.10.X) traffic is being routed through VPN and on the **local** network (192.168.0.X) I can ssh (22) or make requests to the webserver (80). I can reach it internally no problem.

Now the issue: When I try to connect remotely to the Pi I cannot reach my services anymore. That means I cannot SSH (22) nor http (80) from outside the network. I find it odd that in my local network I can used them but outside my network I cannot find them. The second I turn openvpn off i can reach them and everything is working as is again.

I tried to look for a solution the this on the internet but the answer were vague and not very helpful.

What am I missing here?

Comment: What you want cannot be achieved without policy routing. By default, responses to your connection attempts from the Internet are directed to the VPN connection.

Comment: Yes, I do understand the problem. But my knowledge of openvpn, iptables and routing is minimal and I need someone to show me how to solve it by explaining to me what to do next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Thanks to Daniel B's comment I think I solved it. I went and read about policy routing and I used the following tutorial as an example:

https://blog.scottlowe.org/2013/05/29/a-quick-introduction-to-linux-policy-routing/

The only difference is where in the example it says:

> ip rule add from 192.168.30.200 lookup custom

I did the following:

> ip rule add from 192.168.0.0/24 lookup custom

This is to get the whole IP range instead of a single IP.

And it is working for days now with no problems.